# Plus minus in angularjs view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/4v2jaaxh/

```
<div ng-repeat="json in myJson">
        <li>{{json.name}}</li>

    </div><h1>
    total:
    </h1>

$scope.myJson = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "banana",
    "price": 12,
    "qty": 3,
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": 12.9,
    "qty": 4,
  }
]
```

How to display total in view layer as I know angular allow expression like plus or minus. Or I should do it in controller level?

Comment: @Ved 12 + 12.9 which is the price.

Comment: @CodyJonas it's bit confusing i thought total =`12*3 + 12.9*4` .plz edit the question

Comment: ou can use Addition assignment (+=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a function in your controller:

```
$scope.getSum = function () {
    return $scope.myJson.reduce(function(a,b) {return a.price * a.qty + b.price * b.qty});
}
```

and then use it in the html:

```
total:{{getSum()}}
```

Here is a working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36meenk9/1/)

Comment: any idea how can I update the total when the selected value changed? http://jsfiddle.net/yx97x0xk/1/

Comment: Cody, You can change the total more simpely: http://jsfiddle.net/320dgd22/
@Rajesh, That's right, I updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can put a function(For price total/ For qty Total - In this case the example is price total) in your controller:

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.myJson = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "banana",
    "price": 12,
    "qty": 3,
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": 12.9,
    "qty": 4,
  }]

  $scope.total = function(){
  var total = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myJson.length; i++){
    total += $scope.myJson[i].price;
   }
   return total;
  }

$scope.total();
})
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lht7fodj/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Addition assignment

```
angular.forEach($scope.myJson, function(val) {
 $scope.totalPrice += val.price;
 $scope.totalQty += val.qty;
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/4v2jaaxh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller write the following code after the array has been defined:

```
$scope.total = 0;
for(var i=0; i< $scope.myJson.length; i++){
    $scope.total += $scope.myJson[i].price * $scope.myJson[i].qty;
}
```

Then in your view make use of interpolation as `{{total}}`.

Better way is to put the above code in a function and call it in your interpolation statement.

Answer (score 0):

put in html:

```
</div><h1>
total:{{mytotal}}
</h1>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.mytotal= $scope.myJson[0].price+$scope.myJson[1].price;
```